# Program crash - how to read appcompat.txt?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, crash-dumps

After the program I am debugging crashes, I am left with heap dump *.mdmp file & appcompat.txt in my Temp directory. I understand that appcompat.txt is an error report. **Is there a description of its format?**

My appcompat.txt lists a number of DLLs. Am I correct assuming that the reason for a crash could have only come from one of the listed DLLs? **Can I limit my debugging effort to the DLLs listed in appcompat.txt?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should list *all* the DLLs used by your process.  So no, not exactly useful for limiting.

Comment: Unless you wrote those DLLs yourself, it's very unlikely that any of them is causing the problem. Have you tried opening the minidump in Visual Studio?

Comment: @molbdnilo In fact, I wrote some of the DLLs myself, the rest were written by my colleagues, but exactly the part where the crash occurs is in the external code for which I do not have any sources or a debugging database. The minidump has no source code attached to it, so it can only show my the disassembly, which is, you will agree, pretty non-informative.

Comment: @PavloDyban: Ouch, that's a real nightmare. You don't have any clue at all (does the crash depend on hardware/input/output/phase of the moon)?

Comment: @molbdnilo No, no clues. I only know that the crash occurs due to heap corruption, but which part of the code causes it remains a mystery. I will try & debug using sources & pdb files as described in the answer below. Maybe this will work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minidump file is far more informative for diagnosing crashes:

- Install [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx&ei=tF31UNSvL8qf0QWVwIDACw&usg=AFQjCNEA-iDfUSIoJxXKZtU1f3s3cIAaXA&sig2=_frzbkxNC-wxEE8RgLUrFA&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k), if you don't already have it.
- Set up the symbol path variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` to point to the [Microsoft symbol server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503)
- Run `Windbg` and do `File -> Open Crash Dump` and locate your `.dmp` or `.mdmp` file
- Type `!analyze -v`.

This will try to isolate the location of the crash.  Note that just because a crash occurs in a particular dll it doesn't mean that is where the bug resides - it could be because an invalid parameter has been passed in from your application code.  The analysis should hopefully show you a meaningful stack and an error code which should help in working out the actual cause of the crash.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the program, but I did not see more infos than with the minidump opened in VS. Most of the call stack functions now have names, but I do not know what exactly fails. If the EXE I want to debug uses QT & boost, do I need debug symbols (and source files) for both of them?

Comment: Yes, you need the debug symbols to get any meaningful crash analysis. Is this an application you've built yourself?  Note that you need the *exact* pdb files that were created when the app was built. Just building from the same sources isn't enough.

Comment: Woof, I need Qt sources & pdb files for v4.6.2 (which isn't the latest & I did not build Qt on my machine), besides some other slightly out-of-date sources like boost and OpenInventor. If I manage to bring all that together & do a meaningful debug, I will let you know! Thx for your reply!

Comment: It's good to get in the habit of storing the pdb files produced as part of your build process as it makes it much easier to diagnose crashes that users experience after the application has shipped.